# Getting CORS error with Vue3 and influxdb2

Tags: apache, cors, vuejs3, influxdb-2

I get a CORS-error when accessing my influxdb2 from a Vue frontend.
The frontend is running local in development mode, the influxdb runs on a server in the network.

[image: CORS-error]
[image: CORS-options-ok]

I used apache as a reverseproxy but don't get it to work.

```
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} OPTIONS
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1 [R=200,L]

    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Methods "POST, GET, OPTIONS, DELETE, PUT"
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Headers "append,delete,entries,foreach,ge>

    ProxyPreserveHost on
    ProxyRequests on
    ProxyPass / http://192.168.1.60:8086/ Keepalive=On
    ProxyPassReverse / http://192.168.1.60:8086/
```

Have you any ideas?
And here is my js code:

```
axios
.post("https://influx.domain/query",{ headers: {
  'Authorization': `Token ${token}`,
  'Content-Type': 'application/vnd.flux',
  },
  data: query
})
.then(response => {
  console.log(response.data)
})
.catch(error => {
  console.log(error)
});
```

Comment: Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "http://localhost:8080" does also not work

Comment: Your screenshot shows that the `Authorization` header is not currently allowed, even though you sent it with `fetch`; that's probably why CORS preflight check fails. Try `Header set Access-Control-Allow-Headers: "Content-Type, Authorization"` instead.

Comment: I tried your suggestion, but it didn't work,... any other ideas?
I also tried to not use localhost but my normal IP and port

Comment: Edit your question and add the CORS error message show in your browser's Console tab. That will help us diagnose the issue.

Answer (score -1):

I got it to work, I had to add *always* to the Apache config, see below:

```
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} OPTIONS
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1 [R=200,L]

    Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
    Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Methods "POST, GET, OPTIONS"
    Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Headers "Authorization, Content-Type"
```